# Unremovable partition after trying to install ubuntu

Tags: macos, partition, dual-boot

I tried to install Ubuntu on my MacbookPro (mid 2015, OS X Yosemite) dual boot, using the following: [How to Dual-Boot OS X and Ubuntu (PDF)](http://courses.cms.caltech.edu/cs171/materials/pdfs/How_to_Dual-Boot_OSX_and_Ubuntu.pdf)

I was finishing up part 3 and Ubuntu was starting to download, until everything froze. Nothing was responding so I force shutdown my computer and now OS X seems to be working fine. However I have a partition disk0s3 (Linux Swap) and a bunch of Free Space I can't get rid of.

```
/dev/disk0
#:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *251.0 GB   disk0
1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
2:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD            182.6 GB   disk0s2
3:                 Linux Swap                         16.4 GB    disk0s3
```

I tried getting rid of them through Internet Recovery but that didn't work either. How can I get rid of the partition and the Free Space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using El Capitan (OS X 10.11), then the document you are referencing will not work as expected.

As for your question. The command below will remove the Linux Swap partition.

```
sudo diskutil erasevolume "Free Space" "" /dev/disk0s3
```

The next command expands your Macintosh HD volume to contain the free space.

```
sudo diskutil resizevolume /dev/disk0s2 R
```

> Note: I am not sure if the prefix `sudo` is necessary. (But, it will do no harm if you include the `sudo`)

Comment: The first command didn't work (something about not being able to find that partition) but the second command got rid of the Free Space.

Comment: What version of OS X are you using? Yosemite (OS X 10.10) will generate an error message when the first command is used, but the command still removes the partition.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try: open Disk Utility, select the Linux Swap partition, in the toolbar there should be a delete disk option, try that, and try to remove the partition.
2. If 1 didn't work, try use First Aid in Disk Utility (first on the partition and then on the main drive)
3. If 2 didn't work, try to [boot in to Recovery Mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314), select Disk Utility from the menu, and try option 1 and 2 again.

Comment: In DiskUtility, I selected the partition and choose "Erase" at the top. But it failed with the error "MediaKit reports no such partition."

Comment: Did you try in recovery mode?

Comment: Recovery mode wasn't able to start up. The estimated time to start kept going up.  David's solution worked for me, however

Comment: You have no recovery partition to boot to. If you did, then the partition would have appeared in your posted output of the `diskutil list` command.

Comment: Actually, the *OS X Recovery over the Internet* keys are Command-Option-R. Other key combinations can be found at the Apple web site: [Startup key combinations for Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201255).